# Scrolling zoom effect in masked image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a scrolling zoom effect as working on the site mentioned below but I'm not able to achieve a full zoom.

Also, I try to zoom clipped shape / text on scroll but the whole div get scroll in that.

As I've set zoom breakpoint to `document.body.clientWidth / imgElement.clientHeight` but can't find the alternative way.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample SS]

[Sample Link of website](https://www.accenture.com/in-en#block-section-3)

```js
const zoomElement = document.querySelector('.zoom')
const afterZoomElement = document.querySelector('.afterzoom')
const imgElement = document.querySelector('h2')
const WIDTH = document.body.clientWidth
const HEIGHT = zoomElement.clientHeight
const IMAGE_WIDTH = imgElement.clientWidth
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = imgElement.clientHeight
const ZOOM_SPEED = 200 // Lower is faster
const ZOOM_BREAKPOINT = WIDTH / IMAGE_HEIGHT // When it should stop zooming in
const IMAGE_HEIGHT_MAX = IMAGE_HEIGHT * ZOOM_BREAKPOINT
const ABSOLUTE = ZOOM_BREAKPOINT * ZOOM_SPEED // Absolute position, when the Element reached maximum size

// Fade --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const FADE_SPEED = 400 // Lower is faster
let fade = 1
let prev = 0
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Fade

function anim() {
    let scroll = window.scrollY
    let temp = scroll / ZOOM_SPEED
    let zoom = temp > 1 ? temp : 1

    // Only update the Elements scale, when we are below the breakpoint
    if (zoom < ZOOM_BREAKPOINT) {
        // Only scale the Image, so the Zoom element does not mess with the document width
        imgElement.style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`
        // Sets the Elements position to fixed, so it can resize without scrolling away
        zoomElement.style.top = '0px'
        zoomElement.style.position = 'fixed'
    } else {
        // Makes sure the Element always reaches Max Size
        imgElement.style.transform = `scale(${ZOOM_BREAKPOINT})`
        // Sets the elements position to absolute, so it will scroll with the rest of the document
        zoomElement.style.position = 'absolute'
        zoomElement.style.top = ABSOLUTE + 'px'
    }

    // Fade --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    let dif = prev - scroll

    if (zoom < ZOOM_BREAKPOINT - FADE_SPEED / ZOOM_SPEED) {
        fade = 1
    } else if (zoom > ZOOM_BREAKPOINT) {
        fade = 0
    } else {
        fade += dif / FADE_SPEED
    }

    fadeElement.style.opacity = fade
    prev = scroll
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Fade
}

// Resets scroll position on every reload
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => window.requestAnimationFrame(anim))

// Fade --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
zoomElement.style.opacity = 1
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Fade

// Positions the afterZoom element right below the zoomed image
afterZoomElement.style.top = ABSOLUTE + IMAGE_HEIGHT_MAX / 2 + HEIGHT / 2 + 'px'
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: url(https://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m87dri70zh1qzla33o1_500.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.zoom {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.afterzoom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

h2{
  font-size: 5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: url(https://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m87dri70zh1qzla33o1_500.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
  <h2>i</h2>
</div>
<div class="afterzoom">
    <p>This should appear after the above element is fully zoomed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. btw fadeElement is not defined in the code you provided so I commented that. Adjust the zoom brakepoint based on how much you want it to zoom in.

```js
function anim() {
        let scroll = window.scrollY;
        let temp = scroll / ZOOM_SPEED;
        let zoom = temp > 1 ? temp : 1;
    
        // Update the scaling for the text or shape
        if (zoom < ZOOM_BREAKPOINT) {
            imgElement.style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`;
            zoomElement.style.position = 'fixed';
        } else {
            imgElement.style.transform = `scale(${ZOOM_BREAKPOINT})`;
            zoomElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            zoomElement.style.top = `${ABSOLUTE}px`;
        }
    
        // Update the fade transition
        let dif = prev - scroll;
        fade = (zoom < ZOOM_BREAKPOINT) ? 1 : 0;
        fade += (zoom >= ZOOM_BREAKPOINT && zoom <= (ZOOM_BREAKPOINT + (FADE_SPEED / ZOOM_SPEED))) ? dif / FADE_SPEED : 0;
        //fadeElement.style.opacity = fade;
        prev = scroll;
    
        // Adjust the afterZoomElement position
        afterZoomElement.style.top = `${ABSOLUTE + IMAGE_HEIGHT_MAX}px`;
    }
```

```css
.zoom {
        overflow: hidden;
        /* Other styles */
}
```